# cover batch class querylocator and execute method in test class

Tags: unit-test, batch

this is my class

```
global class SFA_UpdateAccountBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    String strParameter;
    boolean isUpdAccountOwnerbatch;
    String query;
    Boolean isWeeklyBatch;


    public SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(String filterStr){
        strParameter=filterStr;
        isUpdAccountOwnerbatch=true;
        query=SFA_KSUtil.getAccountQueryString(filterStr);
        system.debug('query:'+query);
    }

    public SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(String filterStr,Boolean isWeekly,Boolean isNotrunbatch){
        strParameter=filterStr;
        isWeeklyBatch = isWeekly;  
        isUpdAccountOwnerbatch=isNotrunbatch;      
        query=SFA_KSUtil.getAccountQueryString(filterStr);
        system.debug('query:'+query);
    }

    public SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(String filterStr,boolean isNotrunbatch){
        isUpdAccountOwnerbatch=isNotrunbatch;
        query=SFA_KSUtil.getAccountQueryString(filterStr);
        system.debug('query:'+query+'isUpdAccountOwnerbatch:'+isUpdAccountOwnerbatch);
    }

    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<account> scope){
       List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();

       for(account acc : scope){
           acc.Named_Account_Name__c='';
           acc.Named_City__c='';
           acc.ZIP_Code_Group__c='';
           accList.add(acc); 
       }

       //update accList;
       Database.update(accList,false);
    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
         AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, 
                            Status, 
                            NumberOfErrors, 
                            JobItemsProcessed,
                            TotalJobItems, 
                            CreatedBy.Email
                        FROM 
                            AsyncApexJob 
                        WHERE 
                            Id = :BC.getJobId()];                         

       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
       mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
       mail.setSubject('Orgnization Name:'+UserInfo.getOrganizationName()+' Orgnization Id :'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId()+' UpdateAccountOwnerBatch batch Status : ' + a.Status);

       mail.setPlainTextBody('UpdateAccountOwnerBatch batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems + ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
       Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

       String updAccOwnrBatFilterStr = strParameter;
       if(!isWeeklyBatch){
           strParameter += ' ' +LABEL.SFA_ACCOUNT_BATCH_YESTERDAY_FILTER;
       }

       /*Invoke SFA_UpdateAccountOwner_Batch  */
        if(isUpdAccountOwnerbatch){
            Database.executeBatch(new SFA_UpdateAccountOwner_Batch(strParameter),10); 
        }
    }
}
```

---

constructor part is covering but not covering database.querylocator method,execute and finish

This is my test class code

```
@isTest
public class SFA_UpdateAccountBatch_Test {

    static testMethod void unitTestBatch(){
        String str = 'test';
        User u = SFA_TestFactory_Helper.createTestUser('Sales Engineer');
        test.startTest();
        system.runAs(u) {
            SFA_UpdateAccountBatch objAccbatch = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(str);
            SFA_UpdateAccountBatch objAccbatch_two = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(str,true);
            SFA_UpdateAccountBatch objAccbatch_three = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(str,true,true);

        }
         test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your batch to cover the line

```
test.startTest();
        system.runAs(u) {
            SFA_UpdateAccountBatch objAccbatch = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(str);
            SFA_UpdateAccountBatch objAccbatch_two = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(str,true);
            SFA_UpdateAccountBatch objAccbatch_three = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(str,true,true);
           Database.executeBatch(objAccbatch ); //run the batch for first instance for remaining two create separate method.


        }
         test.stopTest();
```

But due to standard limit you need to create three separate method to run this batch three times other wise you will get an exception.

Comment: it give an error message System.QueryException: unexpected token: '&lt;EOF&gt;'

Comment: @cloudZigZag thats related to your query. You need to fix that.

Comment: no @tushar_briskmind not solved yet

Comment: @cloudZigZag your original issue is related to run the batch which I think thats fixed. After running the batch if you get another error then a new question will be good in that case.